# Excel Macro to Pivot Hundreds of Columns into Only 3

Tags: excel, vba

I receive a weekly report containing hundreds of columns. The columns are for each week, and contains two subcolumns of measures (sales amount, units solds).

I'd like to convert these columns into just 4: Client name, week, sales amount, units sold. I've successfully written a macro that does this, and it ran pretty fast initially but is since running *extremely* slow. I think the only change that occurred was my IT department updated my Excel 365 version.

So if I have this data:

```
Client Name | Week 1 Sales | Week 1 Units | Week 2 Sales | Week 2 Units ...
___________________________________________________________________________

    ABC Co  | 100,000      | 10           | 150,000      | 21        ...
```

I'd like to convert it to this:

```
   Client Name |  Week  | Sales   | Units
   ______________________________________

    ABC Co     | Week 1 | 100,000 | 10

    ABC Co     | Week 2 | 150,000 | 21
```

etc

```
numCols = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(dataSh.Range("1:1"))
numRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(dataSh.Range("A:A")) + 1

For i = 3 To numRows
    For j = 2 To numCols Step 2
        If dataSh.Cells(i, j) <> "" Then

            pivotStartRng.Offset(matches, 0) = dataSh.Cells(i, 1)
            pivotStartRng.Offset(matches, 1) = dataSh.Cells(1, j)
            pivotStartRng.Offset(matches, 2) = dataSh.Cells(i, j)
            pivotStartRng.Offset(matches, 3) = dataSh.Cells(i, j + 1)

            matches = matches + 1

        End If

    Next j

Next i
```

The main body of the code looks at each cell of the report data, and if it isn't blank it copies those results over to the consolidated data tab. It loops through about 15,000 cells (150 columns x 100 rows).

I also tried a code that essentially copied and pasted each column over to the data sheet, and then deleted the blank rows. But that ran slow too.

My question is, will this type of macro that loops through 15,000 cells always run slow, or is that not the hang up here? That is, would I be better served writing my macro differently?

**UPDATE** I ran the original code this morning and it worked pretty fast. The range I was pasting to was a table with lookup formulas to the left, that copy down the rows when the data is pasted. It seemed that this was slowing things down considerably, and when I removed the table and ran the macro, it ran extremely fast. I'm not sure if pasting to tables in Excel is something that would cause it to run so slowly, or if there is something else going on?

Comment: Load all the data into a variant array, loop that array and load another variant array then post the variant array onto the new sheet.  Limit the number of time vba references the data on the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Load all the data into a variant array, loop that array and load another variant array then post the variant array onto the new sheet. Limit the number of times vba references the data on the worksheet.

```
numcols = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(dataSh.Range("1:1"))
numrows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(dataSh.Range("A:A")) + 1

Dim dat As Variant
dat = dataSh.Range(dataSh.Cells(3, 2), dataSh.Cells(numrows, numcols)).Value

Dim odat As Variant
ReDim odat(1 To ((UBound(dat, 2) - 1) / 2) * UBound(dat, 1), 1 To 4)

matches = 1

For I = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 2)
    For J = LBound(dat, 2) + 1 To UBound(dat, 2) Step 2
        If dat(I, J) <> "" Then

            odat(matches, 1) = dat(I, 1)
            odat(matches, 2) = dat(1, J)
            odat(matches, 3) = dat(I, J)
            odat(matches, 4) = dat(I, J + 1)

            matches = matches + 1

        End If

    Next J

Next I

pivotStartRng.Resize(UBound(odat, 1), 4).Value = odat
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I've not worked with arrays a ton so I'll have to spend some time on this to understand what's going on. I will say throwing this in my code as is produced some weird results, but worked very fast! So if I can dissect this a little bit and tailor it to my spreadsheet then I think I'll have a winner.